# How to prevent user from clicking button more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to prevent user from clicking the submit button more than once. I tried a number of things which are on SO for similar issue.

**Like for example :**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">
    $('<% =btnUpload.ClientID %>').click(function () { this.disabled = true });
</script>
```

**I also tried..**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">
  $("form").submit(function() {
    $(this).submit(function() {
        return false;
    });
    return true;
  });
</script>
```

**and also tried...on master page**

```
<form onsubmit="if(submitted) return false; submitted = true; return true">
```

But to no use.. 
I am still able to click on button more than once.

**Markup**:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" class="blue-button" 
CssClass="ButtonText"OnClick="btnUpload_Click"
 OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure that you want to Save entered details ?'))
 return false;return doCustomValidate(event,true);"
     Text="Save" />
```

Also note that I am using master page so

Comment: Once the form submits the page probably reloads, and you start over again, all javascript is lost.

Comment: not related, but for ease of JS/jQuery set your button control ClientIDMode to "Static" then in the jQuery you can use standard referencing : `$('#btnUpload')`

Comment: why dont you disable in code behind (.cs file) logic like button clicked event

Answer (score 2):

If you want the user to click on the button just once, use `.one()` to attach event.

jquery url : http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 2):

Add a disabled attribute to it.

```
$('#<% =btnUpload.ClientID %>').click(function () {
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed `#` in your `id` prepend it before `<% =btnUpload.ClientID %>` like,

```
$(function(){
    $('#<% =btnUpload.ClientID %>').click(function () {
        this.disabled = true;
    });
});
```

If you want to add click event once only then use [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one) like,

```
$(function(){
    $('#<% =btnUpload.ClientID %>').one('click',function () {
        // your code on click event
    });
});
```

If, your `id` changes(`Clientid changes` after `render`) then try to use `class selector` like,

```
$(function(){
    $('.ButtonText').click(function () {
        this.disabled = true;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set one `count` variable in javascript. initialize it's value as `0`. In `.click()` event listener check the condition. `If` it is `0`, allow to execute the code and increase count by `1`. `Else`, return false.

```
var count = 0;
$('#<% =btnUpload.ClientID %>').click(function () {
    if (count == 0) {
        count++;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```