# How to disable an ASP.NET Button right after first submit (on the client)?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, postback

I have a submit button. On clicking this button the form gets submitted. I want to prevent user from clicking it more than one time. So OnClientClick

function I am using disabling the button like this,

```
$("#btn123").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

But now the problem is my form is not getting submitted.

Even when I return true from my javascript function. Following is my javascript function

```
 function ab() {

        $("#btn123").attr("disabled", "disabled");

        return true;
    }
```

I am also using master page.

Comment: If you want to submit the form then you can disable it on server side using .Visible = false;

Comment: Disabling on the server side will only reflect when the call is completed, so that wont work @Adil

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803461/how-to-prevent-user-from-clicking-button-more-than-once

Comment: I think this link will help you: http://aspsnippets.com/Blue/Articles/Disable-ASPNet-button-after-click-to-prevent-double-clicking.aspx

Comment: You are disabling the button in the button click handler. Why don't you disable the button in the form submit handler? This will make sure that the form gets submitted.

Comment: @AlokRanjan I want button to get freeze after user click once. But disabling button on form submit user will get enough time to click on button several time

Comment: When clicked once on submit button you have added disabled property to submit button having id btn123. If you closely inspect the element in DOM structure  you will find disabled="disabled" added to the submit tag. So, just do one thing just after what ever you are submitting is completed call another function and add `$("#btn123").attr("disabled", "false");` in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that it needs to be bound to the submit of the form. The following code will fix that.

```
$("#formId").submit(function(){
    $("#btn123").attr("disabled", "disabled");
})
```

Comment: This sounded like a good plan, but it didn't work for me - the postback is still prevented if the button gets disabled in the form's submit() event. It might depend on browser/version.

Answer (score 0):

Button is not firing postBack because you have disabled this. The approach to avoid multiple postBack is to have two buttons side by side. Real and dummy. On first click hide/delete the real button and show the dummy one

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="disableButton();"/>

<asp:Button ID="ButtonDummy" runat="server" Text="Button" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick='return false;' style="display:none;"/>
```

and JS:

```
function disableButton() {

 $("#Button1").hide();

 $("#ButtonDummy").show();

 return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is surprisingly obscure for something I would expect to be really common. If you disable the button after it's been clicked, it will prevent the postback from occurring. Even @Rajdeep's suggestion to disable it in the form's submit event doesn't work for me.

I've found the best way is to set the button's UseSubmitBehavior="false":

```
<asp:Button ID="btn123" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="ab()"
    OnClick="btn123_Click" runat="server" />
```

this will cause the server to modify the button's OnClick event to include a javascript call to start the postback so it looks like this in the browser:

```
OnClientClick="ab();__doPostBack('ctl00$btn123','')"
```

this will cause the postback to occur after the function ab() is called, even if btn123 ends up disabled.